# Import registry from here string

Tags: powershell, registry, herestring

Is there any solution to add(import) values to the registry from here string.

```
$regString = @"
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.ps1]
... blha blha blha ....
"@
Some-FunctionOrCommandThatAcceptHereSTRtoReg $regString
```

Comment: Why not using `reg.exe`?

Comment: You could write the string to a temporary file on disk and then run `reg.exe import` against that file.

Answer (score 2):

+++ solution A (Mathias R. Jessen)

Just write HereString to file then use it in reg

```
function HereString-ToRegistry{
    param ([Parameter()] [string] $Regstr)
    $tmp = New-TemporaryFile
    $Regstr | Out-File $tmp
    reg import $tmp.FullName
}
$regstr1 = @"
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}\PropertyBag]
"ThisPCPolicy"="Hide"
"@
HereString-ToRegistry -Regstr $regstr1
```